# Get current date RFC 2616 formated

Tags: android, date, rfc2616

how can I get in my Android App the current date RFC 2616 formatted?

For example: Wed, 05 Apr 2006 21:12:00 GMT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I get it with this methode:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String date = org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils.formatDate(c.getTime());
```